# How to update running Node.js servers?

Tags: node.js, versioning, reverse-proxy

As far as I understand, a Node.js server is basically a JavaScript file, run by the `node` executable. Is it possible to update this file without stopping request handling?

I guess the node executable  must be stopped for this, so I think I should use a reverse proxy. For example:

1. Original server version listens on localhost:50001
2. Proxy server listens to requests on webinterface:80 and forwards them to localhost:50001
3. New server version should be started on localhost:50002
4. Proxy server forwarding target should be changed to localhost:50002
5. Original server version should be stopped

Is this a valid approach? How can such a version update be done automatically on multiple server machines (accessible from the same LAN)?

Comment: I use https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor for windows, it monitors file changes and restart itself. On linux, I use https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever.

Comment: Both tools are great, but they do not help you from preventing your server to restart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A different "pure-node" solution is to use the built-in [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module:

Your code runs as one cluster-client (of many). A cluster-server process binds to the port and does automatic load-balancing between clients. When you've changed the code, you can send a signal to the cluster-server and it will gracefully restart your clients, without dropping any existing connections.

Here are some projects that can do the cluster-server management for you:

- https://npmjs.org/package/cluster-master
- https://github.com/daeq/node-cluster-manager.

Advantages:

- Fewer components in your stack. (Easier to deploy / manage.)
- Can automatically start a node process for each core on the CPU, so your program can fully leverage the underlying hardware.
- No need to learn nginx's config syntax

Answer (score 7):

Basically, what you can (should) do is the following:

- Run a webserver such as Nginx as a reverse proxy
- Use at least two (!) Node.js instances behind it
- Put the sessions in a database such as Redis

When you need to update your system, shut down one of the two Node.js instances, update it, and restart it. Then do the same with the other.

Basically, this should do it.

The downside is that you are potentially running different versions of your application for a small amount of time concurrently, and your database (e.g.) needs to be able to catch up with this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for revoking the accept, but I would prefer a "pure-node" solution. Unfortunately there is no way to accept more than one answer :(